# 2000 Census Population by Block

Tags: us-census, geospatial

I'm trying to get population data from the 2000 Census at the block level for the state of Colorado. This can either be as a shapefile or as a table along with a shapefile containing the 2000 block geographies. Essentially I'm looking to create a shape file which has the block geography along with the population count of each block. These are available for the 2010 census (https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010BLKPOPHU/) but I haven't been able to find them for the 2000 census. I've tried getting the information through some combination of American FactFinder and Tiger but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/TABBLOCK/2000/tl_2010_08_tabblock00.zip

Comment: @AnthonyDamico Do you know if block shapefiles are available with the population included as in the 2010 link above (which was broken I just fixed it). If not is there somewhere to get a table of block #s with population. Sorry for my ignorance I'm new to census data and I've found their website is less than helpful.

Comment: i don't think tiger files with selected demographics appeared until the start of the american community survey in 2005.  merge population by census block info from `summary file 1` if you can't find it elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

Give [`census_area`](https://github.com/datamade/census_area) a try.

Your query would be something like

```
from census_area import Census

c = Census("MY_API_KEY")
blocks = c.sf1.geo_block(('NAME', 'B25034_010E'), year=2000, colorado_geojson['geometry'])
```

It stiches together data from the Census API and Census ESRI servers. (I am an author of `census_area`)

Answer (score 0):

If you know your way around R, the [tigris](https://github.com/walkerke/tigris) package should work. You can use it to pull the shapefiles for 2000, which should also contain population.

Comment: I do know my way around R but it appears the tigris package is just for the tiger polygons and doesn't include population information.